# C# linq select duplicate from an XElement tree

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is my XElement tree

```
        XElement myShoppingList = new XElement("myShoppingList",
            new XElement("Pasadena", new XAttribute("Vendor", "Tesla"),
                new XElement("Car",
                    new XElement("model3",
                        new XElement("Black")))),
            new XElement("LasVegas", new XAttribute("Vendor", "Tesla"),
                new XElement("Car",
                    new XElement("modelY",
                        new XElement("White")))),
            new XElement("Pasadena", new XAttribute("Vendor", "Apple"),
                new XElement("Phone",
                    new XElement("model13",
                        new XElement("Black")))),
            new XElement("Pasadena", new XAttribute("Vendor", "Apple"),
                new XElement("Phone",
                    new XElement("model12",
                        new XElement("White")))));
```

I can't seems to get this working, first question - When searching for "Pasadena" I should be getting 3 repeats:

```
        var query = myShoppingList.Elements().AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.XPathSelectElement("Pasadena"))
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
          .ToList();
```

When searching for Tesla in LasVegas I'm expecting 1 repeat

```
        var query = myShoppingList.Elements().AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.XPathSelectElement("Pasadena[@Name='Tesla']"))
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
          .ToList();
```

And finally I want to search for "White" regardless of who makes the widget then display its maker.  So I'm expecting 2 repeats:

```
       var query = myShoppingList.Elements().AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.XPathSelectElement("../../../White"))
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .SelectMany(y => y})
          .ToList();
```

I'm not able get this working what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I keep getting this return: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Int32]]

Comment: Your GroupBy looks unnecessary in this case. You can simply do `.Select(e => e.Name.LocalName);`. No need of count as well.

Comment: Yes I'm fully aware about select statement under condition that I already know which element to select ahead of time.  However, my actual XML list have random duplicates that I'm trying to identify.  And because they're random I don't know in advance of what to expect.  Hence I can't do a select in advanced.

Comment: @Syntax_MM I think you'll have to elaborate a bit more on what your expectations are here. Your intention by `.GroupBy(x => x.XPathSelectElement("Pasadena"))` is not clear. Each "Pasadena" element is a separate object, so `element1 != element2` and therefore won't be grouped. Do you mean `myShoppingList.XPathSelectElements("/Pasadena")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seems to get this working, first question - When searching for
> "Pasadena" I should be getting 3 repeats:

Is this what you're trying to achieve? :

```
var query = myShoppingList.XPathSelectElements("Pasadena")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() });
```

> When searching for Tesla in LasVegas I'm expecting 1 repeat

You could try it this way.

```
var query = myShoppingList.XPathSelectElements("Pasadena")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes().Any(x => x.Name == "Vendor" && x.Value == "Tesla"))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() });
```

For this one i'm not sure if that's what you want to achieve

```
var query = myShoppingList.XPathSelectElements("//White")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() });
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!.  For the second suggestion, what if I have more XML nodes after "White", what other character to type in place of "//"?

Comment: Glad i could help. If you need a specific child of "//white" you would do "//white/MyChild". At this point you can do a lot from here with either XPathSelectElements or linq.